# getting user-agent info from flask's socketio

Tags: python, websocket, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Is it possible to get user-agent information from socketio in flask? I guess user related information is sent to socket server during handshaking.

If not possible, I will require clients send this information manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. the same way as we do in regular web apps:

```
userAgent = request.headers.get('User-Agent')
```

Comment: Correct. Flask-SocketIO exposes an artificial request context to socket event handlers, that includes all the headers sent by the client on the socket connection request.